Override standard new button with Aura component and display a message
I have overridden the standard new button from Quote object and I want to display a message when user clicks on the button.
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride"access="global">
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<lightning:card title="New Quote">
    <div class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <lightning:formattedText value="Please create your Quote from an Opportunity" />
    </div>
</lightning:card> </aura:component>

I have included this aura component in the button, but when clicking the button the message it's not displayed. The aura component it's working because without it I would be able to choose from a list of record types of quote and I'm not. The only thing missing it's that message.  
Is this a limitation of Salesforce or something it's missing in the implementation?
I would appreciate any advice.

Did you also check the Skip record type selection page?

If you're referring to 'Skip record type selection page' option, yes I tried it. Nothing changed @ShaileshPatil

I tried it in my dev account. It is working for me. Are you using Sales Console or normal Sales app?

I am using Sales Console app. How did it work for you? Steps I follow: I am going to the list view with all the quotes, I am pressing 'New Quote' button and nothing happens, no error message - @ShaileshPatil
